# AMAZON AWS How do i subscribe an endpoint to SNS topic?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns, amazon-cognito

I'm implementing push notifications in an iOS app using Amazon SNS and Amazon Cognito services.
Cognito saves tokens successfully, my app gets notified, everything's working well, but there is a thing.

Now, when still in development, I need to manually add endpoints to an SNS topic, so all subscribers can get notifications. When i'll push an update to the App Store, there will be thousands of tokens to add.

I was studying Amazon AWS documentation, but there was no clue whether it's possible to make it happen without that additional effort.

My question: is it possible to **automatically** subscribe an endpoint to a topic with Amazon services **only**?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? What do you mean by with Amazon services only? Is what you're doing trying to automate subscribing to a topic, and using Cognito as the credentials to do so?

Comment: @JeffBailey thanks for your questions. I've already figured it out, but didn't have enough time to self-answer. I wanted to automate subscribing, but I didn't know that my iOS app is responsible for subscribing an endpoint to a topic, i was thinking that it is possible through Amazon AWS console after calling cognito to save a token.

Comment: "but didn't have enough time to self-answer. " so you're not going to share the answer that you came up with? That's terrible, after others came into help. Be a good SO citizen and share your solution.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no way to **automatically** subscribe an endpoint to a topic, but you can accomplish all through code.

You can directly call the `Subscribe` API after you have created your endpoint. Unlike other kinds of subscription, no confirmation is necessary with SNS Mobile Push.

Here is some example Objective-C code that creates an endpoint and subscribes it to a topic:

```
AWSSNS *sns = [AWSSNS defaultSNS];
AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput *endpointRequest = [AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput new];
endpointRequest.platformApplicationArn = MY_PLATFORM_ARN;
endpointRequest.token = MY_TOKEN;

[[[sns createPlatformEndpoint:endpointRequest] continueWithSuccessBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
    AWSSNSCreateEndpointResponse *response = task.result;

    AWSSNSSubscribeInput *subscribeRequest = [AWSSNSSubscribeInput new];
    subscribeRequest.endpoint = response.endpointArn;
    subscribeRequest.protocols = @"application";
    subscribeRequest.topicArn = MY_TOPIC_ARN;
    return [sns subscribe:subscribeRequest];
}] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
    if (task.cancelled) {
        NSLog(@"Task cancelled");
    }
    else if (task.error) {
        NSLog(@"Error occurred: [%@]", task.error);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Success");
    }
    return nil;
}];
```

Make sure you have granted access to `sns:Subscribe` in your Cognito roles to allow your application to make this call.

**Update 2015-07-08:** Updated to reflect AWS iOS SDK 2.2.0+

Comment: I've figured it out by myself, and it's the right (and only?) way. Thanks anyway, your answer may be helpful for someone else in the future.

Comment: @cyborg86pl It is possible to subscribe via the console, but that is much more of a manual process.

Comment: Bob, can you please tell me why my subscriptions stopped at quantity of 2000 while app endpoints are still growing? I know that topics has 10M limit, so where is the problem?

Comment: @cyborg86pl If you are viewing in the console, the console only shows a limit of 2,000 subscriptions. If you need to see all subscriptions, you will need to use the raw APIs.

Comment: Ok, thanks, so there is no need to worry. It would be great if Amazon was giving a hint like i see it now in "Subscriptions" tab with 10100 limit.

Comment: It seems that AWSSNSSubscribeInput `protocol` changed for `protocols`.

Comment: @BobKinney sorry to bother you. AWS has changed something. And this code doesn't work. I have the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31286823/s3-static-site-hosting-with-my-domain-why-aws-manual-doesnt-work-for-me and I completely don't understand how to subscribe to SNS topic from my iOS app...

Comment: @user3742622 the question you linked doesn't seem to be at all related to this one. Can you please link to a relevant question or tell what problem you are encountering?

Comment: @BobKinney Thank you for the answer, you are my last hope. Sorry about link the right is this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31300136/amazon-aws-sns-how-do-i-subscribe-to-sns-topic-from-ios I have some problem with your code I have got two errors there: 1."Incompatible block pointer types sending 'id (^)(BFTask *__strong)' to parameter of type 'AWSContinuationBlock'" and 2."Incompatible pointer types sending 'AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput *' to parameter of type 'AWSSNSCreatePlatformApplicationInput *'" When I try to fix it my way it doesn't work I get `Error occurred: [Error D...`

Comment: @user3742622 The first error would indicate that you are not using the latest SDK (with 2.2.x we switched BFTask to AWSTask). The second is a typo, that I'll correct.

Comment: @BobKinney I changed `continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task)` to AWSTask and error has gone. But I don't understand about `Incompatible pointer types sending AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput * to parameter of type AWSSNSCreatePlatformApplicationInput *... You said about latest SDK, but I am already using AWS SDK 2.2. I wrote about my error in my topic for not duplicating.

Comment: This code just isn't working for me.  First, the latest SDK is choking on `BFTask *task` in the `continueWithBlock`.  Switching that to an `AWSTask` helps, but my subscription still fails and the `task.error` is 0.  Are there any other updates in the latest SDK (2.4.11 I believe) that would affect this?

Comment: @BobKinney how can i unsubscribe and subsribe end point using on/off button? i have settings options push notification on / off in settings page

Answer (score 3):

This is the original code to subscribe an endpoint to a topic in `Swift3`

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

    //Get Token ENDPOINT
    let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})

    //Create SNS Module
    let sns = AWSSNS.default()
    let request = AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput()
    request?.token = deviceTokenString

    //Send Request
    request?.platformApplicationArn = Constants.SNSDEVApplicationARN

    sns.createPlatformEndpoint(request!).continue({ (task: AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
        if task.error != nil {
            print("Error: \(task.error)")
        } else {

            let createEndpointResponse = task.result! as AWSSNSCreateEndpointResponse
            print("endpointArn: \(createEndpointResponse.endpointArn)")

            let subscription = Constants.SNSEndPoint //Use your own topic endpoint

            //Create Subscription request
            let subscriptionRequest = AWSSNSSubscribeInput()


              subscriptionRequest?.protocols = "application"
                subscriptionRequest?.topicArn = subscription
                subscriptionRequest?.endpoint = createEndpointResponse.endpointArn

                sns.subscribe(subscriptionRequest!).continue ({
                    (task:AWSTask) -> AnyObject! in
                    if task.error != nil
                    {
                        print("Error subscribing: \(task.error)")
                        return nil
                    }

                    print("Subscribed succesfully")

                   //Confirm subscription
                    let subscriptionConfirmInput = AWSSNSConfirmSubscriptionInput()
                    subscriptionConfirmInput?.token = createEndpointResponse.endpointArn
                    subscriptionConfirmInput?.topicArn = subscription
                    sns.confirmSubscription(subscriptionConfirmInput!).continue ({
                        (task:AWSTask) -> AnyObject! in
                        if task.error != nil
                        {
                            print("Error subscribing: \(task.error)")
                        }
                        return nil
                    })
                    return nil

                })

            }
            return nil

        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use static credentials instead of using AWSCognito you will need to create those through Amazons IAM console.

Here is the code for initializing the Amazon in your App Delegate

```
    // Sets up the AWS Mobile SDK for iOS
    // Initialize the Amazon credentials provider
    AWSStaticCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider =[[AWSStaticCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithAccessKey:AWSAccessID secretKey:AWSSecretKey];

    AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:DefaultServiceRegionType credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

    [AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
```

Fissh

Comment: Not sure if it's a good idea, AWS SDK indicates to not use AWSStaticCredentialsProvider in production : `We strongly discourage embedding AWS credentials in your production apps because they can be easily extracted and abused. Consider using 'AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider'`

Comment: I completely agree Popei, I should have mentioned the warning.

Comment: Well this is the basic consideration when applying any of the AWS services & certainly not an answer to the question above.