# Amazon AWS SNS: How do i subscribe to SNS topic from iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-cognito

First of all I found the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26974852/amazon-aws-how-do-i-subscribe-an-endpoint-to-sns-topic), but it doesn't work... Maybe AWS SDK changes or something else, I don't know why... I want to subscribe to SNS topic from my iOS app. I am trying to do it with code from that answer, which I tried to change to get rid of errors:

```
AWSSNS *sns = [AWSSNS defaultSNS];

    AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput *endpointRequest = [AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput new];

    endpointRequest.platformApplicationArn = @"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:753780999999:app/APNS_SANDBOX/MyAppDevelopment";
    endpointRequest.token = [self deviceTokenAsString:deviceToken]; 

    [[[sns createPlatformApplication:endpointRequest] continueWithSuccessBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {

        AWSSNSCreateEndpointResponse *response = task.result;

        AWSSNSSubscribeInput *subscribeRequest = [AWSSNSSubscribeInput new];

        subscribeRequest.endpoint = response.endpointArn;
        subscribeRequest.protocols = @"application";
        subscribeRequest.topicArn = @"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:753780999999:MyAppDevelopingTest";

        return [sns subscribe:subscribeRequest];

    }] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {

        if (task.cancelled) {
            NSLog(@"Task cancelled");
        }

        else if (task.error) {
            NSLog(@"Error occurred: [%@]", task.error);
        }

        else {
            NSLog(@"Success");
        }

        return nil;

    }];
```

But I get the error:

```
Error occurred: [Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSSNSErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSSNSErrorDomain error 0.)" UserInfo=0x17ee0950 {Type=Sender, Message=3 validation errors detected: Value null at 'name' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null; Value null at 'attributes' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null; Value null at 'platform' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null, __text=(
    "\n    ",
    "\n    ",
    "\n    ",
    "\n  "
), Code=ValidationError}]
```

Why so? Why does the resource cut after app/ is it ok? Beside this I don't understand where I should put deviceToken?
I really need help! Thanks in advance?

My Cognito role is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sns:CreatePlatformEndpoint",
                "sns:Subscribe",
                "sns:CreatePlatformApplication",
                "sns:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:sns:*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using the latest AWS SDK:

```
Installing AWSCognito 2.2.1 (was 2.2.0)
Installing AWSCore 2.2.1 (was 2.2.0)
Installing AWSSNS 2.2.1 (was 2.2.0)
```

Comment: Message=User: arn:aws:sts::753780999999:assumed-role/Cognito_MyAppUnauth_Role/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: SNS:CreatePlatformApplication

Comment: No. I've tried to add that role. The mistake is same. I completely don't understand why the resource cuts... Why "is not authorized to perform: SNS:CreatePlatformApplication on resource: arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:753780999999:app/," instead of "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:753780999999:app/APNS_SANDBOX/MyAppDevelopment"... Anyway, I don't know what is wrong...

Comment: Are you positive that you've modified the correct role? Have you tried changing the Resource to "*" to see if that unblocks you?

Comment: @BobKinney Ok, I modified my cognito's role to *. Now I have error:  `Error occurred: [Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSSNSErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSSNSErrorDomain error 0.)" UserInfo=0x17ee0950 {Type=Sender, Message=3 validation errors detected: Value null at 'name' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null; Value null at 'attributes' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null; Value null at 'platform' failed to...` and etc...

Comment: @BobKinney I changed `continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task)` to AWSTask and error has gone. But I don't understand about `Incompatible pointer types sending AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput * to parameter of type AWSSNSCreatePlatformApplicationInput *... You said about latest SDK, but I am already using AWS SDK 2.2.

Comment: @BobKinney And I've updated my question by your comment with new code, role and error.

Comment: @user3742622 The pointer issue is due to a typo in the code you copied. sns createPlatformApplication:endpointRequest should be sns createPlatformEndpoint:endpointRequest.

Comment: @BobKinney Sorry for delay. Man, many-many thanks!!! It's really helps!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, unfortunately you copied code that included a typo:

```
createPlatformApplication:endpointRequest
```

Should be:

```
createPlatformEndpoint:endpointRequest
```

The method CreatePlatformApplication was not allowed in your original policy. Once you allowed sns:*, the call was allowed by the service, but the request didn't include the required parameters for CreatePlatformApplication, hence the ValidationError. The trimmed ARN in your original message is also a result of lack of parameters for CreatePlatformApplication.