# AWS SNS Endpoint subscription to a topic

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns

Instead of creating an endpoint in an application and using that endpoint to create a subscription in a topic, Is it possible subscribe to a topic directly with the Registration Id. Also just want to know if it is possible to do it in PHP.

Please help me here.

Answer (score 0):

It's not to possible subscribe an endpoint to a topic directly with the Registration Id (or token). You will first need to subscribe the device to an Application. You can then send direct pushes to the endpoints or subscribe them to your topics.

Note that "when you delete an endpoint that is also subscribed to a topic, you must also unsubscribe the endpoint from the topic", it's not unsubscribed automatically ~ http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_DeleteEndpoint.html.

You can use AWS SDK for PHP to subscribe your endpoints to your topics, for more information, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.Sns.SnsClient.html#_subscribe

Comment: After creating the endpoint in an application, can we automatically subscribe the Endpoint to the topic ?

Answer (score 0):

AWS does not provide a way to do that automatically, but you can easily handle it in your code.

Take a look at [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26974852/amazon-aws-how-do-i-subscribe-an-endpoint-to-sns-topic) for more information and sample code in Objective-C: "*You can directly call the **Subscribe API** after you have created your endpoint. Unlike other kinds of subscription, no confirmation is necessary with SNS Mobile Push*".